# javaScript in ASP with MasterPage

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have some problem with page under masterPage. my little soft generates random value with sharp code, and then counts i from 0 to value with client script. When I run program without masterpages it works, but when I tried to run it from nested page it doesn't work. here my code:

masted page has only ContentPlaceHolder.
nested web form:

```
asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

sharp code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
        int q = rnd.Next();
        Label1.Text = q.ToString();

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.Page, typeof(Page), "counter", "myjs.js");
        Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "counter(); return false;");
```

script:

```
function counter() {
var q = Number(document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML);    
var i = Number(document.getElementById("Label2").innerHTML);
if (i < q) {
    i += 1;
    document.getElementById("Label2").innerHTML = i;
    setTimeout(function () { counter(); }, 10);
}
}
```

The error here **var q = Number(document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML);** and text of error: **Runtime error Microsoft JScript: Object required**

Comment: in order to prevent duplicate ids, when you have a master page, all controls have their ids changed (a prefix is added). So your "Label1" doesn't have that id anymore -- if you look at the HTML source or use the Chrome inspector or Firebug you'll see what the real id is.

Comment: set the asp Controls you want to target with javascript to `ClientIDMode="Static"` and the controls will retain their original ids when pumped out as client ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the element instance using `getElementById`, because the ASP.Net engine are changing the generated client Id in the resulting HTML.

To avoid that, if you are using the .net framework 4 or later, you can add the `ClientIDMode="Static"` property in the server controls you want to have the same client and server ID.